# Issue while reading Input from a file in iteration in Batch Processing

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have an issue while reading from a input file the below shown values(FILE.txt) .
The < > symbols cause an improper read . I tired using ^(escape character but its of no use ,I also tried Double quotes("") and the result is same messed up output.

Is there anyway I can read the contents of the file in iteration with the < > = characters .
Please help

```
FILE.txt contains

A;Select * from TablenameA where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime;XXX;YYY
B;Select * from TablenameB where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime;AAA;YYY
C;Select * from TablenameC where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime;BBB;YYY


--------------SCRIPT----------------------------------
SET vFILENAME=FILE.txt
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%i in (%vFILENAME%) do call :process "%%i" "%%j" "%%k" "%%l"
goto END

:process
    set VAR1=%~1
    set VAR2=%~2
    set VAR3=%~3
    set VAR4=%~4


    echo %VAR1%
    echo %VAR2%
    echo %VAR3%
    echo %VAR4%

----------------------SCRIPT-END----------------------
```

Update : Quotes removed from for loop "%vFILENAME%" .

Question Update : What if I want to redirect the output into a different file

Example :

```
        echo PrmOne=%VAR1%>Output.txt
        echo PrmTWO=%VAR2%>>Output.txt
        echo PrmTHREE=%VAR3%>>Output.txt
        echo PrmFOUR=%VAR4%>>Output.txt
```

Comment: Enclose both the variable and its value in quotes: `set "VAR1=%~1"`, and use SET /P to show the values: `set /P "=%VAR1%" & echo/`

Comment: that does not work @Aacini

Comment: The file name is in quotes so you need to use the **usebackq** option wit the FOR /F command.

Comment: That is not the issue here . When I give a file without < > = symbols the script works fine and reads everything .

Comment: @jjames, why do you need to assign the passed arguments to an environmental variable first and then echo them.  You can just use the passed arguments as is with pretty much any command unless you need to do string manipulation.

Comment: @jjames, there is no way in h e double toothpick that your script is passing the contents of the file to your function if the file name is quoted within the FOR /F command.  You have to use the **usebackq** option when the filename is quoted!

Comment: @jjames: I assumed your code works and you only have problems with the special chars! `:/` See my answer below...

Comment: @Squashman above one is just an example .

Comment: @jjames: Precisely! You should realize that we take your code _as you posted it_, and your "example" just not works because the file name was enclosed in quotes. It is a very bad idea to edit your question and remove the quotes with no advice, because all comments and answers related to this point are meaningless after such change! **`:(`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have a couple errors (besides the quotes problem): the `for /F` command requires `usebackq` option because you enclose the file name in quotes:

```
@echo off

SET vFILENAME=FILE.txt
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%i in ("%vFILENAME%") do call :process "%%i" "%%j" "%%k" "%%l" < NUL
goto :EOF

:process
    set "VAR1=%~1"
    set "VAR2=%~2"
    set "VAR3=%~3"
    set "VAR4=%~4"


    set /P "=%VAR1%" & echo/
    set /P "=%VAR2%" & echo/
    set /P "=%VAR3%" & echo/
    set /P "=%VAR4%" & echo/
```

Output:

```
A
Select * from TablenameA where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime
XXX
YYY
B
Select * from TablenameB where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime
AAA
YYY
C
Select * from TablenameC where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime
BBB
YYY
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works . Can you please help me more . I would like to redirect VAR1,VAR2 ,VAR3,VAR4 into a file .
Like echo Myname=%VAR1%>file.txt
echo SQL=%VAR2%>>file.txt
echo abc=%VAR3%>file.txt

Comment: @jjames,if that was the original intent of your script then you should have declared that in your original question.

Comment: @Squashman: well, the OP posted imprecise and incomplete information in the question because it "is just an example", right?

Comment: @Aacini Sorry guys you took it the wrong way or rather I might have conveyed the same . ,What I meant is The above is an example I made (a sloppy one ) and not the actual large script cause it would not serve the purpose but rather be much confusing (business rules and stuff)

Comment: Again and again: we understand that you post just a small example of your code (this is the right way to do it), but you must understand that we copy and run your code _exactly as you posted it!_ In conclusion: you should tested the example code before posted it and quickly fix the problem as soon as we noted it, instead of discuss that "the quotes in the filename are not the issue". IMHO you should recognize this point at least...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the double quotes in argument:

```
for /?

FOR /F .. ("string")
```

the line should be

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%i in (%vFILENAME%) do call :process "%%i" "%%j" "%%k" "%%l"
```

otherwise the string "FILE.txt" is used as input

UPDATE, after comment the < > symbols are used for indirection the echo needs then double quotes